# HttpGet request with params and image in the body of the request

Tags: java, android

I need to upload an image on server using a Http Get request with params and image in the body of the request

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. HTTP GET requests have no body.

You would need to make a HTTP POST request.